Presigned URL PutObject with Flutter and Golang
I'm trying to upload images to my S3 bucket using presigned URLs. My bucket has no public access, and the CORS policy is this:
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": ["*"],
        "AllowedMethods": ["PUT"],
        "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]

I generate a presigned URL using the Go sdk v2:
func GenerateImagePresignedUrl(
    ctx context.Context,
    client *s3.PresignClient,
    userID string,
) (*sigv4.PresignedHTTPRequest, *string, error) {
    exp := time.Duration(time.Duration(60).Minutes())

    suffix := fmt.Sprintf("%v.jpg", time.Now().Unix())
    key := fmt.Sprintf("mobile-users/profile/%v/%v", userID, suffix)

    params := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(os.Getenv("S3_BUCKET_NAME")),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    }
    req, err := client.PresignPutObject(ctx, params, s3.WithPresignExpires(exp))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }
    return req, &key, nil
}

However, after this point I am completely lost. I cannot seem to match the signature, and I keep getting 403 errors. This is the Flutter code that I'm using:
Future directS3Upload({required S3PresignedObject s3Object, required File file}) async {
  final data = await file.readAsBytes();
  final uri = Uri.parse(s3Object.url); // s3Object.url = presigned URL generated in Go
  final res = await put(uri, body: data);

  print(res.statusCode);
  print(res.body);
  print(res.reasonPhrase);
  print(res.headers);
}

I don't know what I'm missing at this point, as I've tried so many combinations of content types, additional fields, and headers. I am only ever uploading images, never video content, so the content type shouldn't be an issue?

Your Go code varies from the example, for example: opts.Expires = time.Duration(lifetimeSecs * int64(time.Second)) - not sure if this is relevant. Have you got the complete Go example to work? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example_s3_Scenario_PresignedUrl_section.html

I’ve also set the expiration in the PutObjectInput object, that doesn’t make a difference, it still outputs a URL with expiration set to 60 minutes. The go code is working, it always gives me a pre signed URL. I’d assume it would give me an error otherwise? Not too sure.

Are you able to use the presigned URL obtained to access the URL from Go, as in the complete example at the bottom of the page linked above? Are you able to use the same URL from, say, Postman?

Yes, when I followed the tutorial in the docs you linked I was able to upload it using the Go script as well as using curl.

Is it something specific to the PUT verb? Can you GET a pre-signed get URL? Can you update the question with a test signed GET URL valid for a day?

I'm not sure, but when I compare the presigned URLs from my lambda function and running the go tutorial locally (both create URLs in the same way), the lambda-generated URL has a massive X-Amz-Security-Token value that the local one does not have. Does this have anything to do with IAM permissions? My lambda has authorization to perform PutObject, but that's it.

I was able to get on the right track with this related question that was seeing similar issues. I had given permissions to my lambda function to access my bucket and perform PutObject operations, but I only included access to the bucket, and not to any objects within the bucket. I modified my terraform IAM permission from this:
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_allow_write" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["s3:PutObject"]
    resources = [local.s3_digital_content_bucket_arn]
  }
}

To this:
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3_allow_write" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["s3:PutObject"]
    resources = ["${local.s3_digital_content_bucket_arn}/*"]
  }
}

I needed to set the wildcard at the end of the resource in order for the policy to work. As unexciting as this answer is, it is the answer that has finally fixed my problem. I no longer get 403 responses from my Flutter client.
I also modified my Go lambda to create the pre-signed URL to match the tutorial code from the AWS docs, just to be safe:
func GenerateProfileImagePresignedUrl(ctx context.Context, client *s3.PresignClient, key string) (*sigv4.PresignedHTTPRequest, error) {
    params := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(os.Getenv("S3_BUCKET_NAME")),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    }
    req, err := client.PresignPutObject(ctx, params, func(opts *s3.PresignOptions) {
        opts.Expires = time.Duration(300 * int64(time.Second))
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return req, nil
}


Buckets and Objects are different things and support different operations which is why a bucket ARN is not usable for object-level actions.
